# How to set textwidth in Overleaf source?

Tags: overleaf

I know that you can use vim key bindings in Overleaf (and even some ex commands). I was wondering if there was any way to set the textwidth of the source document to 80 (as you would in vim via `:set tw=80` -- I tried this in Overleaf but it says `command not found`) so that it would automatically insert a new line when the line is more than 80 characters long.

To be clear, I am not trying to insert new lines into the actual compiled pdf document, just the source (for easier readability and editing).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Overleaf-specific questions should be directed at the Overleaf help desk. Overleaf's LaTeX support staff is top notch.

Comment: Tom from Overleaf Support here. I'm afraid that we don't support this sort of features in the Vim keybindings, which only provide a limited subset of the standard Vim behaviour. Sorry for the limitation.

Comment: @yo' T'would be nice tho!  I'm using emacs and git, my colleagues are using overleaf only, and it's a bit of a mess to work together because of that…